# Is there a player that allows copying currently shown susbtitles to the clipboard?

Tags: subtitles, video-player

I'm on Windows 7 and have video files with external or built-in (not hard-coded) subtitles. When watching the videos, I'd like to be able to somehow copy the currently shown text to the clipboard.

Do you know any video player that can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select and copy subtitles on youtube. If you have your subs in a common format, you can upload them to youtube with the video and your subtitles will be applied according to the internal timecode in the subtitles-file. Then, when playing back the video, you can select and copy the subs.